# Compiling error of deploying app into android device using QT

Tags: android, qt

I am developing an app using QT for android on Window Platform. And I encountered a problem when I clicked 'Build' button for the android project. The error message showed that "
`Cannot run target compiler 'C:\Android\android-ndk-r16b-windows-x86_64\android-ndk-r16b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++'. Maybe you forgot to setup the environment?`"

When I clicked 'Run' to the project, the error message showed that

```
"Cannot find the androiddeploy Json file.
Error while building/deploying project PhotoViewer (kit: Android for armeabi-v7a (GCC 4.9, Qt 5.9.3 for Android armv7))
When executing step "Deploy to Android device"".
```

I checked the correctness of my compiler location and they are correct. I am not sure what I did wrong for the config setting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you correctly installed and configured all prerequisites for Android QT development ?

regarding `Cannot run target compiler 'C:\Android\android-ndk-r16b-windows-x86_64\android-ndk-r16b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++'`

Check if Android NDK and the path in the error message does exist, QT is sure to work with ndk r10e.
if you are new to QT android development, you need to follow instructions here :
[Installing the Prerequisites](http://Cannot%20run%20target%20compiler%20'C:%5CAndroid%5Candroid-ndk-r16b-windows-x86_64%5Candroid-ndk-r16b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++')

Comment: Thanks for your reminder. I reinstall the android ndk, and then it works now.